# Hibernate insert ID into auto-increment column

Tags: mysql, hibernate, auto-increment

I am using Sprint Boot, Sprint Data JPA, Hibernate 4 and MySQL. I have a table with an autoincrement column. I can insert new entities ok and the column auto-increments. Sometimes though I want to specify the ID when doing an insert but Hibernate appears to ignore any ID value I set.

Table definition:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "example")
public class Example implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    ... more columns ....
}
```

How can I have both auto-increment when no id is set AND allow setting of the ID by my application?

Answer (score 0):

Its because your ID is not that will be stored in the database,rather than that it is considering  **@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)** which is generating values for you

Comment: Yes, I have that because its an auto-increment column. My question was how I can also insert an ID rather than have MySQL auto-generate one. Using straight SQL, MYSQL allows you to insert a value for an ID column or if not specified it will generate one for you. I want to achieve via Hibernate.